# Change the shape of hyperlink borders in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to change the borders of hyperlinks in a Beamer presentation from rounded to rectangles (as is possible with blocks). I haven't been able to figure out how to do this, but seems like it should be straightforward. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The title}
\label{thelabel}
\hyperlink{thelabel}{\beamerbutton{thetext}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is build in way to do so, but you can simply define the button to suite your taste.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{button}{%
    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{{\insertbuttontext}}%
    \ht\beamer@tempbox=6pt%
    \dp\beamer@tempbox=0pt%
    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\vbox{\box\beamer@tempbox\vskip2pt}%
    \beamer@tempdim=\wd\beamer@tempbox%
    \beamer@dima=\beamer@tempdim\advance\beamer@dima by2.2pt
    \beamer@dimb=\beamer@tempdim\advance\beamer@dimb by4pt
    \begin{pgfpicture}{-2pt}{0pt}{\the\beamer@tempdim}{8pt}
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{button frame}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\beamer@dimb}{8pt}}
        \pgfusepath{fill}
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    \hskip2pt
    \hskip-\beamer@tempdim%
    \box\beamer@tempbox%
    \kern4pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{The title}
        \label{thelabel}
        \hyperlink{thelabel}{\beamerbutton{thetext}}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]